# Eloquent query for user's Monday 9am by timezone

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've been Googling aggressively but can't quite work out how I'd do it.

If I have a timezone for all my users (e.g `'Australia/Melbourne'`), and am running a `cron` job every hour, is there a way to query for every user for whom it's currently 9am on a Monday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first you should get all timezones in the database, then pick the one for which it's 9am:

```
$tzs = User::select('timezone')->distinct()->pluck('timezone');
$applicableTimezones = $tzs->filter(function ($timezone) {    
     $localTime = Carbon::now(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
     return $localTime->hour == 9 
            && $localTime->minute == 0  
            && $localTime->dayOfWeek == Carbon::MONDAY;
});

$users = User::whereIn('timezone', $applicableTimezones)->get();
```

This does require 2 queries but if you are using an index for the timezones it will not require the database loop through all users and instead use the index.

Answer (score 0):

What about in your cron job checking the time like this:

```
$mondayMorning = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('D H:i', 'Mon 09:00', 'Australia/Melbourne');

if(Carbon\Carbon::now()->eq($mondayMorning))
{
    // So here query all the users where the timezone is met. Because this condition should be 
    // satisfied only at that time.

    $users = User::where('timezone', 'Australia/Melbourne')->get();
}
```

Comment: To do that, I'd need to `foreach` every user in the database, rather than directly query for it. Do you know of a way to write that as an Eloquent query?

Comment: Sorry I did not understood your initial question right. How do you know for which users the time is Melbourne timezone? Do you have a metadata on where they are?

Comment: Yes, I have a column in the `Users` table with their timezone in it. I'm trying to query all `Users` every hour for users whose timezone would mean they're at 9am on a Monday.

Comment: So my code was good. You don't have to foreach every user but just select the ones that are in that timezone. Look at my edit.

Comment: `Australia/Melbourne` was just an example - in that case it only works for one timezone, and I needed it to work for every time zone. Thanks for the help, though!